# Why is the ionic v1 event `beforeLeave` returning data from after it has left the view

Tags: ionic-framework, side-menu

I have an app with two tab views, view 1 and view 2. When I switch to view 2, I need to do some things in view 1, before it switches to view 2. As part of this, I have the following code.

```
 $scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeLeave', (event) => {
    const stateName = $ionicHistory.currentStateName()
    console.log('beforeLeave', stateName)
  })
```

When I switch to view 2, I expect the console.log to print `view 1` as the stateName, however it prints `view 2`, which is counterintuitive because I would expect to return the state before I leave the view ie `beforeLeave`.

Is there perhaps some other event I need to listen to?

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like the event `$stateChangeStart` does the trick that I am looking for, and what I would expect `beforeLeave` to do.